# Sound output from laptop

Tags: audio, system-sounds, 3.5mm

I have a laptop which has both 3.5 mm jack and type C connector. Is it possible to get sound output from 2 headphones which are connected to 3.5 jack and Type C?

Currently when I connect both headphones, sound output is only coming from type C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, no you can't.

What you should do is split the 3.5mm connection with a y-splitter.

[image]